# What does "folly and fool" mean in this sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence

I am reading the Wikipedia entry for [Clown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clown), as for some reason I thought they would be close to Religion historically, and found this sentence

> "It seems plausible that folly and fools, like religion and magic,
> meet some deeply rooted needs in human society."

Source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clown history section

What does "folly and fools" mean in this sentence, as I can not see how the standard meaning would fit in. It seems to me that it may mean Clown to some extent but cant be sure.

Comment: [*What the author is pursuing in this brief but intriguing test is the continuous presence of **clowning and clowns** in dominant contemporary playwrights such as Pirandello.*](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Italiana/k1RdAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22clowning+and+clowns%22&dq=%22clowning+and+clowns%22&printsec=frontcover) Same juxtaposition of singular noun *(the **activity**)* and plural noun *(the **performers** of that activity)*, for emphasis / completeness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Fool*, as well as meaning a foolish person, used to be another word for a court jester (someone employed to entertain a king or high-ranking person).

Oxford definition 2: HISTORICAL - a jester or clown, especially one retained in a royal or noble household.

*Folly* is the state of being a fool, or the activities of fools.

Comment: "It seems plausible that the kind of comedy that jesters/clowns provide meets a deeply-rooted need in human society, in the same way that religion and magic do."

Comment: Folly & fool may be more than kith & kin here, more than alliteration and emphasis without added meaning. Maybe folly here means native joy, childlike silliness, and the sheer release we all appreciate from fun.